# Sampling and concatenate nth rows and n+1 rows and following rows in High dimensional Matrix

Tags: python

I have a matrix size of X = 1963x4. My goal is to concatenate nth rows, n+1th rows and n+2th rows from the X matrix.For example row numbers are like [nth rows = 1,151,302,.., n+1 row = 2,152,303,...,and follows.

The below code only gives a new matrix of nth rows. How to concatenate n+1 rows and follows. Let me know how to proceed.

import numpy as np

matrix = np.ndarray(shape=(10,3))

rows = np.shape(matrix)[0] #number of rows

columns = np.shape(matrix)[1] #number of columns

l = range(rows)[0::3] #indexes of each third element including the first element

new_matrix = np.ndarray(shape=(len(l),columns)) # new matrix

for i in range(len(l)):`

```
new_matrix[i] = matrix[l[i]] #adding each third row from matrix to new_matrix
```

Comment: Can you try to clarify? I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: Please include minimum reproducible code. We want to see your research and effort, not just write some code for you

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, you want a slice of your list. You can do it like this:

```py
# Your list
X = [...]

X[n:n+m+1]
```

where:

`n` is a lower boundary

`m` is an upper boundary

E.g.
For rows from 500 to 510:

```py
X[500:511]
```